# tablerow not taking up full width of table layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablelayout

I have a question about tablelayouts in android using framelayouts. However, the code works but the rows that I add through java dont align properly with the table, the wrap up in the start. [image]

Date - 1/2/17
Session Time - 05:00:00 
Average speed - 29

TrainingHistory.java

```
package com.example.spuck.fragment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.spuck.R;

import java.sql.Time;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import static android.support.design.R.id.center;

/**
* A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
* Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
* {@link TrainingHistory.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
* to handle interaction events.
* Use the {@link TrainingHistory#newInstance} factory method to
* create an instance of this fragment.
*/
public class TrainingHistory extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

// ----------------------------- //
View view;
int[] POINTS_ARRAY;
int[] AVERAGE_SPEED;
long[] SESSION_TIME;
TableRow tableRow;

TextView date, avg_speed, session_time;

List<String> START_TIME_STRING_LIST;
List<String> END_TIME_STRING_LIST;


// ----------------------------- //
public TrainingHistory() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment TrainingHistory.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static TrainingHistory newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    TrainingHistory fragment = new TrainingHistory();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_training_history, container, false);
    date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date_training_history);
    avg_speed = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.avg_speed_training_history);
    session_time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.session_time_training_history);
    tableRow = (TableRow) view.findViewById(R.id.tableRow1);
    return view;
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Bundle b = this.getArguments();
    AVERAGE_SPEED = b.getIntArray("speed");
    SESSION_TIME = b.getLongArray("session_time");
    TableLayout tl=(TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.maintable);

    for (int i=0;i<AVERAGE_SPEED.length;i++)
    {
        date = new TextView(getContext());
        avg_speed = new TextView(getContext());
        session_time = new TextView(getContext());

        tableRow = new TableRow(getContext());
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams( TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        Date d = new Time(SESSION_TIME[i]);
        date.setText("1/2/17");
        avg_speed.setText("" + AVERAGE_SPEED[i]);
        session_time.setText("" + d);

        date.setGravity(center);
        date.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
        avg_speed.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
        session_time.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);

        tableRow.addView(date);
        tableRow.addView(session_time);
        tableRow.addView(avg_speed);

        tl.addView(tableRow, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    }


}


@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
   /* if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }*/
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
}
```

I want the textviews to align properly with the images Date, Session and speed above, what should i do?

**XML FILE**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/home_fragment">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="107dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/the_one"
                    android:id="@+id/the_one"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1000dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/the_upperblank"
                    android:layout_below="@id/the_one"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:id="@+id/the_upperblank"
                    />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_below="@id/the_one"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_one_training_history"
                        >

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/the_date"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:id="@+id/the_date" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/the_session_time"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:id="@+id/the_session_time"/>

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/the_average_speed"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:id="@+id/the_average_speed"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/maintable"
                android:layout_below="@id/linear_layout_one_training_history"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/date_training_history"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Date"
                        android:visibility="invisible"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="4.6"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/session_time_training_history"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:visibility="invisible"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:text="Session Time"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/avg_speed_training_history"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Average Speed"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:visibility="invisible"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your xml file my friend

Comment: post your xml file instead of Java code

Comment: @RajeshKushvaha edited

Comment: remove `android:layout_weight="4.6"` from textview and check tablerow layout will auto adjust as per bigger size from cloumn

Comment: remove weights from all the textviews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set weight to textview which are date, avg_speed etc in java dynamically like

```
TextView txtview = new TextView(v.getContext());
LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
txtview.setLayoutParams(params);
```

where 1f is weight as 1, you have just give different weights as per your needs.

Comment: when i add this it doesnt show the textview at all, without this it does

Comment: Try this // Get our View (TextView or anything) object:
View v = findViewById(R.id.our_view); 

// Get params:
LinearLayout.LayoutParams loparams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();

// Set only target params:
loparams.height = 0;
loparams.weight = 1;
v.setLayoutParams(loparams);

Comment: this method worked, insted of linearlayout i changed it to tablerow and it worked, thanks

Comment: quick question, can i center align them by this same method?

Comment: yes you can view.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM);

Answer (score 1):

I think you also want fixed header row. I would suggest you to use this library https://github.com/InQBarna/TableFixHeaders. It will save you a lot of time.